# Is it okay for performance to use a lot of ID tags?

Tags: html, performance, dom, browser, tags

As mentioned in title, I want to find out if there is really some performance overhead when using a lot of ID tags in html.

I know the difference between CLASSes and IDs, but I'am not sure about their performance. As far as I know, IDs have specific functionality both for JS and Browser. Browser stores them in it's memory somewhere, and JS uses it to get it from Browser's memory to access them much faster than traversing the whole source code in searching of a specific CLASS.

So, if I don't need to access the ID's with JS or anything else, will be it reasonable to use them in HTML markup?

Comment: Remember each ID can only be used _once_ in the page.

Comment: Yes, i know it, the reason why I asked, is that each ID is unique, and stored in Web Browser for futher manipulation(or something like that), so I want to find out if there is any impact on performance because a lot of IDs ?

Comment: *"Browser stores them in it's memory somewhere, ..."* - It does?

Comment: Not sure if it's directly stored in it's memory or just linked somehow with them. But i've read somewhere that IDs are managed by Browsers too. And a lot means for about 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The simple answer is yes but usually not much unless there are many
>   hundreds or thousands.

The detailed answer to this question (as stated) is "it depends".

It depends on:

Your definition of 'a lot'.
Some folks would consider 100 a lot, others a 1000, others 10,000

Which browser being used and the version of the browser.

The machine being used, how fast the cpu is, etc.

The OS being used.

The internet (regional/local) speed at that time to download all the div tags.

Where the div's are and if any of the page can load without them.

In conclusion:- given we're talking about web apps and many differences based on user clients, keep the number of div's low if possible.

Comment: I try to ask in another way: Is there somewhere said, that we should keep the number of IDs as low as possible ?

Comment: Yes.  I also added a one-liner to the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have never noticed a degradation of performance as the number of id's are used in HTML tags.

The thing that would degrade performance in my opinion would be the use of client side scripting to manipulate the HTML the ID's are assigned to in mass.

This is my opinion based on experience. No research completed on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, i've made a research and now i'am pretty sure there is not performance issue in use of IDs..

Comment: no, not so many, i think just above 500, but no performance degradation remarked.